# Reputation to Vote Down

Tags: soporte, reputación, privilegios

Earlier I had the 125 reputation to vote down. So far, I have made only one downvote in spanish.stackexchange. But now, my reputation is only 118. How can I get back my 125 reputation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Three of your last questions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/26420/arunabh-bhattacharya?tab=questions&sort=newest) were not well-received and earned you some downvotes. Receiving a downvote reduces your reputation by 2, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/295232). You could

- improve those questions so that they start earning upvotes
- gain more reputation in other ways (asking a new good question, posting a good answer, suggesting an edit)
- if you've given up on a question and don't think it can be improved any further (i.e. it was a poor question to begin with), you can delete it; this will return the reputation you lost to the downvotes on them. This is not possible if there is already an upvoted answer, and deleting too many questions might lead to a question ban.

Answer (score 5):

Your questions often seem to be rather distanced from the aims of the site. They often ask for an explanation of something which is common to many languages or they focus on a coincidental fact. People have tried to find answers to them but often these amount to saying "Well, that is how it is" which does not help you very much in your studies of the language. Perhaps worth bearing in mind that this is a small site and there is only a handful of people who provide most of the answers and so if they have not found it easy to give an answer to your question which they can be proud of they will soon give up and you will not get the help you want.

Comment: I am glad to read this and had pointed out a similar situation. Yet no one agreed with me. Yet here, you have 5 upvotes. Congratulations. :)